# Postgres replace characters in string

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have column with text where I need to change characters!
For example

- �ay----> need to be Day
- �rag---->need to be Drag

So I need to replace � with character D.
I try next but I get error:invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

```
update  tableT pp set descript=(select regexp_replace(descript,'�', 'D') 
FROM 
  tableT kk where pp.id=kk.id) ;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
update tableT pp
set descript = (select replace(descript, '�', 'D') from tableT where id = pp.id)
```

Why don't use replace?

Answer (score 14):

It's just a plain `UPDATE`:

```
update  tableT set descript= regexp_replace(descript,'�', 'D')
```

add `where descript like '%�%'` to minimize transaction.

Or, as President Camacho says, why not use `replace` instead of `regexp_replace`?

Comment: plus 1 on the added `WHERE`